# Casting concrete type to Any?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a use case where I want to assign an array of objects of a specific type to a variable of type `[Any]`.  Considering these references:

```
var genericArray : [Any]
let specificArray : [MyClass]
```

This throws a compiler error:

```
genericArray = specificArray  
//Cannot assign value of type '[MyClass]' to value of type '[Any]'
```

And so does this:

```
genericArray = specificArray as [Any]
//'Any' is not a subtype of 'MyClass'
```

This works:

```
genericArray = specificArray.map { $0 }
```

But it seems less than elegant.  Is there a better way to handle this assignment?

Answer (score 0):

If your genericArray hold instances of class types only (not including function types) then just use `var genericArray : [AnyObject]`. That will work because specificArray type is set to MyClass which is class I guess